# Are JavaScript browser Cache objects made by CacheStorage threadsafe?

Tags: javascript, cachestorage

If I use `CacheStorage.open()` to get the same `Cache` in the UI thread as in a Worker thread, and begin reading/writing from/to it on both sides, is it safe? Or can there be race conditions? I'm hoping the Cache API is thread safe (I would assume that it is, like all else in JS).

Answer (score 0):

> is it safe?

Yes. All methods return Promises, as the Cache might be managed by another thread, the Promise then resolves if the other thread performed the operation. There cannot be concurrent modifications or other such weird things.

> Or can there be race conditions?

Whenever there are multiple threads there can be race conditions, thats in the nature of things. That means that if you `add()` a cache entry while trying to retrieve it woth `get()` from another WebWorker in parallel might or might not get you a result.

Comment: So it is possible to delete a cache key on one thread and set the same key on the other thread, and we can't tell which one will finish first right?

Comment: Is there anything about this behavior explicitly written somewhere? It could be nice if the API would return something that indicates that an operation underway in some other thread, and to be able to wait for the next opportunity. Seems that between checking if a key exists and then setting the key if it doesn't, that some other thread could sneak a value in there first, in which case the other threads value will be discarded. Is this something we have to explicitly guard against with coordination code?

Comment: @trusktr why would you need that? Does it matter if the new entry will be added in a millisecond or in 10 hours?

Comment: Well like I tried to explain, it can result in unexpected results without coordination. Let me try to explain the case I have in an existing code base: One thread checks if a key exists, if it doesn't then later on in the same async function sets the key. Another thread also responsible for creating the same keys can make the key between when the other thread checked if it existed and when it wrote the key, therefore this presents a likely unexpected sequence of events. Not that I want it that way, that I now see that I have that situation in the code I'm looking at. Gotta fix it.